# Cómo puedo esuchar 2 inputs a la misma vez y validar que no esten vacios para funcionar?

Tags: javascript

Con este codigo puedo escuchar 2 inputs al cambiar pero las validaciones no me funcionan

```
<input type="text" id="inputOne">
    <input type="text" id="inputTwo">
    <p id="result"></p>

    <script>
        let inputOne = document.querySelector('#inputOne');
        let inputTwo = document.querySelector('#inputTwo');
        let result = document.querySelector('#result');
        document.addEventListener('change', function(e){
            if(e.target.inputOne !== "" && e.target.inputTwo !== ""){
                result.textContent = parseInt(inputOne.value) + parseInt(inputTwo.value);
            } else {
                result.textContent = "void";
            }
        })
    </script>
```

Quiero validar que los 2 inputs contengan algo, al contener ambos algo entonces me hagan la operacion y si alguno queda vacio entonces el input de resultado quede vacio. He intentado y no he dado con la solucion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma fácil seria tener un event handler comun que aplicas a ambos controles (evitas poner un handler global, que seria invocado ante cualquier cambio en cualquier control), finalmente en el event handler verificas que ambos inputs tengan datos (ojo no hice ninguna validacion que sean realmente numericos) y completas la operacion.

```js
const inputOne = document.querySelector('#inputOne');
const inputTwo = document.querySelector('#inputTwo');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');

const calculaSumaSiHayValores = () => {
  const value1 = inputOne.value
  const value2 = inputTwo.value
    
  if (value1 && value2) {
    const total = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2)
    result.innerText = total
  }
}

inputOne.addEventListener('change', calculaSumaSiHayValores);
inputTwo.addEventListener('change', calculaSumaSiHayValores);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputOne">
<input type="text" id="inputTwo">
<p id="result"></p>
```

Si queres que reaccione a medida que escribis, podes cambiar el evento a input

```js
const inputOne = document.querySelector('#inputOne');
const inputTwo = document.querySelector('#inputTwo');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');

const calculaSumaSiHayValores = () => {
  const value1 = inputOne.value
  const value2 = inputTwo.value
    
  if (value1 && value2) {
    const total = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2)
    result.innerText = total
  }
}

inputOne.addEventListener('input', calculaSumaSiHayValores);
inputTwo.addEventListener('input', calculaSumaSiHayValores);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputOne">
<input type="text" id="inputTwo">
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!